# Changing php version on apache (using XAMPP) using homebrew on a mac, httpd change ignored?

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, homebrew

I installed php 5.4 using homebrew, and verified version 5.4 via terminal `php -v`.

I commented out the previously used load modules for php4/5, and inputted the suggested line in httpd.conf for apache:

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/opt/php54/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But my localhost is still using php5.6.11 according to `phpversion()`.

I am on a mac running Yosemite.

Any ideas?